# Why does my code fault when Inserting a node at the end of a double-linked list?

Tags: c

Im learning C and i need to Create-Delete the head and the tail of a double list, im having troubles when i want to create a tail after i deleted all the nodes.
this are the functions where i add and delete:

```
struct nodo{
int code;
char name[30];
char last[30];
struct nodo *next, *prev;
};// fin struct nodo
static struct nodo *head = NULL, *tail = NULL;
struct nodo *inserthead(struct nodo *new_aux){
    if(head == NULL && tail == NULL){
        new_aux->next =NULL;
        new_aux->prev =NULL;
        head = new_aux;
        tail = new_aux;
     }// fin if
    else{
        new_aux->prev = NULL;
        new_aux->next = head;
    head = new_aux;
    }// fin else
    return head;
}
struct nodo *insert_tail(struct nodo * new_aux){
    if(head == NULL && tail == NULL){
     new_aux->next =NULL;
        new_aux->prev =NULL;
        head = new_aux;
        tail = new_aux;
}// fin if
    else{
        struct nodo *tmp =head;
        while(tmp->next!=NULL){
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }// fin while
        new_aux->prev = tmp;
        tmp->next = new_aux;
        tail = new_aux;
    }// fin else
return tail;
}// fin insertar cola
struct nodo *removehead(){
    if(head!=NULL){
        struct nodo *temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(temp);
    }// fin if
    else{
        return NULL;
    }// fin else
    return head;
}// fin elimina head
struct nodo *remove_tail(){
    if(head == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }//fin if
    else if(head->next == NULL){
        struct nodo *tmp = head;
        free(tmp);
        head = NULL;
    }// fin else if
    else{
        struct nodo *aux_one = head;
        struct nodo *aux_two = head->next;
        struct nodo *aux_three = head;
        while(aux_two->next!=NULL){
            aux_two = aux_two->next;
            aux_one = aux_one->next;
        }//fin while
        aux_one->next = NULL;
        while(aux_three->next!=aux_one){
          aux_three = aux_three->next;
       }
     aux_one->prev = aux_three; 
    tail = aux_one;
    free(aux_two);    
    }//fin else
}//fin remove cola
```

and here is the main:

```
int main(){
    struct nodo *nuevo;
    int option;
    int continuar = 1;
    printf("\n\t BIENVENIDO\n");
    while(continuar==1){
        printf("\n->1.-Ingresar nodo al principio\n->2.-Ingresar nodo al     final\n->3.-Eliminar primer nodo\n->4.-Eliminar ultimo nodo\n->5.-Mostrar     nodos\n->");
       scanf("%d",&option);
        switch(option){
           case 1:
               nuevo = (struct nodo*)malloc(1*sizeof(struct nodo));
                printf("\n->Ingresa un codigo: ");
                scanf("%d", &(*nuevo).code);
                printf("\n->Ingresa un nombre: ");
                scanf("%s",(*nuevo).name);
                printf("\n->Ingresa un apellido: ");
                scanf("%s",(*nuevo).last);
                inserthead(nuevo);
        break;
        case 2:
            nuevo = (struct nodo*)malloc(1*sizeof(struct nodo));
            printf("\n->Ingresa un codigo: ");
            scanf("%d", &(*nuevo).code);
            printf("\n->Ingresa un nombre: ");
            scanf("%s",(*nuevo).name);
            printf("\n->Ingresa un apellido: ");
            scanf("%s",(*nuevo).last);
            insert_tail(nuevo);
        break;
        case 3:
            removehead();
        break;
        case 4:
            remove_tail();
        break;
        case 5:
            printlist();
        break;
    };//fin switch
    printf("\n->Deseas continuar? 1.-Si 2.-No ");
    scanf("%d", &continuar);
};//fin while
return 0;
}// fin main :D
```

the problem is "segmentation fault" when i try to add a tail after deleting all the nodes or when i try to add a head after deleting all the nodes. I dont have this problem when i create for first time a tail or head, same for deleting without nodes.

thanks for your time :D

Comment: Were you planning on *doing* something with all those return values? Because `main()` doesn't seem to give two-cents for them. And fwiw, this is *considerably* easier with pointers-to-pointers.

Comment: "I get segmentation fault" We all get segmentation faults. Fire up a debugger, grab a paper and pen if needed and be the master of your code!

Comment: Yeah.. if not a wall of code, it's a high kerb.  Essentially, what @bolov says.  Go, Go gadget debugger!

Comment: There is a need to synchronize(Maintain consistency) the `head` and `tail`.

Comment: I'll grab a paper! thanks for your time! :D btw, the pointers prev & next are ok?